# What does the [max] mean when using replace string in Python?

Tags: python, string, replace

So I was trying to use the replace string method:

> print("one one one one one one".replace("one","three"[3]))

I though the result would be:

> three three three one one one

But it turned out to be:

> e e e e e e

And when I replaced it with:

> print("one one one one one one".replace("one","three"[2]))

It turned out to be:

> r r r r r r

So I'm just not really sure what the [max] means in the string method. Isn't it supposed to be the limit on the number of replacements?

Comment: Strings are sequences, so you can index them. `.replace("one","three"[3]))` is saying "replace all occurrences of the string 'one' with index 3 of the string 'three'", which happens to be "e"

Comment: Also note in the documentation: `string.replace(s, old, new[, maxreplace])`... the square brackets are used to indicate that `maxreplace` is an _optional_ argument, _not_ that it should be specified using square brackets itself. Notice that there's a comma inside the square brackets before `maxreplace`, so you should pass it just like any other argument _if you choose to include it_. I think that's the source of your confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
print("one one one one one one".replace("one","three"[3])
```

You are selecting index number three of the string "three", which is "e".  So all "one"'s are replaced with "e"

You are looking for this.

```
print("one one one one one one".replace("one","three",3))
```

Answer (score 2):

there is no comma between "three" and [3]. code must be like

```
"one one one".replace("one", "three", 2)
```

otherwise it will slice "three" string.